# how to get the relative path to include javascript functions file

Tags: javascript, relative-path, absolute-path

I have following directory structure

```
dir1
   dir2
     dir3
     dir4    
       file1
     dir5
       file2
```

I want to access file1 that is in directory4 in file2 that is in directory5. I have tried using absolute as well as relative paths.

Could anyone help me how to access this file ?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the question well, you have this directory-structure:

```
| dir1
| dir2
| dir3
| dir4
|   >> file1
| dir5
|   >> file2
```

In that case, you can use `../dir4/file1`